# How to use additional .net libraries in xamarin cross platform app

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I'm building an application in xamarin that will be a cross platform app.  It is using xamarin forms and is a PCL project.
As I was developing i noticed that alot of functions are not available. For example system.datatable or dns.GetHostEntry
When i go to add these references, none is available to add under my PCL project at the top. The other android/ios/uwp projects actually allow to use these functions. But since its a PCL it has to be done in the portable project.
My question is how can i utlize a cross platform pcl app to use functions that get domain hostname or use of datatables instead of such a limited amount of features.

Comment: In this situation I was using DI to create interface which each platform has to implement. Simply in runtime just regiester it on each platform. If you cannot do it in PCL I think you have to implement that in each platform

Comment: a dl? please explain

Comment: Using dependency injection is one approach, you define a common interface and implement it in each platform project.

Comment: it's call DependencyService in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

In PCL :

```
 public interface IIPAddress
 {
    string GetIPAddress();
 }
```

In Native Platform:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(App1.Droid.IPAddress))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
public class IPAddress : IIPAddress
{
    public IPAddress()
    {

    }
    public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress[] adresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        if (adresses != null && adresses[0] != null)
        {
            return adresses[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```